# Where are original photos in Samsung Gallery stored?

Tags: samsung, photos, gallery

In the Samsung Gallery app, we can edit photos and overwrite the original. Yet, we can somehow revert it. So the app seems to be saving original photos somewhere.

2 questions:

1. Where are they stored?
2. How to remove them?

I cannot find any info online about this.

Comment: it's in Samsung Gallery app data

Comment: Then can i remove those data _only_?

Comment: yes, if you clear app data from settings this won't touch DCIM/Camera directory

Comment: @alecxs it doesnt work

Comment: on my (MIUI) Gallery there is no such option to revert edits. instead, each edited file is saved as new file in original location with different name, while the original file remains untouched

Comment: Its a mystery to me too.  I suspect it may be in the cloud

Comment: _Where_ in the cloud? I dont think so
Edit: there is another app for Samsung photo editing (not gallery). clearing data there doesnt help either